# UISegmentedControl to show mapTypes swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to ios development, researched the case on google and not found anything related. I am developing in one swift viewcontroller maps. So far so good, in this ViewController i insert UISegmentedControl with options of Satellite, Standard and Hybrid. When I open the app with the Standard does not appear any problem, but when I click on the Satellite or Hybrid means the screen goes black and the folowing messages appear in the debug area:

"Error: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context and is Thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This is a courtesy notice: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update. "

"Error: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context and is Thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This is a courtesy notice: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update. "

Follows the code.

```
IBOutlet Var turcoMapaView: MKMapView! 

    
     
IBOutlet Var segmentControl: UISegmentedControl! 

    
     IBAction Func tipoDeMapa (sender: UISegmentedControl) {

         {switch segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex 

         case 0: 

             turcoMapaView.mapType = MKMapType.Standard 

         case 1: 

             turcoMapaView.mapType = MKMapType.Satellite

         case 2: 

             turcoMapaView.mapType = MKMapType.Hybrid 

         default: 

             turcoMapaView.mapType = MKMapType.Standard 

         } 

      
     }
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have several syntax errors in your function.  To make it easy to test I changed the variables:

```
var a = 0

@IBAction func changeMap (sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    switch a {

    case 0:

        a = 1
    case 1:

        a = 2
    case 2:

        a = 3
    default:

        a = 4
    }

}
```

There should be "@" before IB outlets and actions.  Functions have a lowercase f in func.  Your brackets are in the wrong locations in your switch statement.

Comment: Thanks for reply. 
I made the changes and the problem continues, the type of map changes, but gets the odd screen when zoomed in or out

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't look at the map issue per se because of the syntax issues.  Will have to wait until after work today.

Comment: OK - it is not obvious to me from just the segmented control.  Usually an invalid context is a call to something else that is empty or nonexistent.  Can you post your project to github?

Comment: Hello! Thanks again!! Here is my project URL: https://github.com/leandrospc/BarDoTurco

Comment: Okay thanks.  I am traveling today and will see if I can get to it tonight.  If not, tomorrow.

Comment: Hello again, i made a test and in the ios simulator the maps works fine, but in the physical device appears the error

Comment: Okay, will load it on my phone later and take a look.

Comment: After the iOS update to 8.0.2 version, the map begins to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
IBOutlet Var turcoMapaView: MKMapView! 

IBOutlet Var segmentControl: UISegmentedControl! 

IBAction Func tipoDeMapa (sender: UISegmentedControl) {

     switch segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex { 

     case 0: 

         turcoMapaView.mapType = .Standard 

     case 1: 

         turcoMapaView.mapType = .Satellite

     case 2: 

         turcoMapaView.mapType = .Hybrid 

     default: 

         turcoMapaView.mapType = .Standard 

     }
 }
```

This would be the correct way to get you segment control to work. your biggest issue was your placement of curly brace for your switch statement.